# Probability regression models

Tags: regression, probability, optimization

I have 2-d data points and have probabilities for those data points (which are of the order of 10e-8). Now I have some functional form of the probability distribution (which has a complicated parameterisation of mean and covariance matrix - total number of parameters are 14). Now I want to find optimal parameters of the model which fits these observed probabilities. I am using PyTorch for doing this.

Total number of data points: 6000 for 2-D data points I have range of column 1: 0 to 6 range of column 2: 0 to 5

I am currently using mean squared error (which is probably wrong) and the loss at initialisation is very large and with epochs loss is decreasing and is converging to some value which is still very large for eg. from 10e12 to 10e8. I tried for 1000 epochs but nothing much improved. I even tried KL divergence loss but in that the loss instead of converging showed fluctuations. I am using Adam optimiser.

I have the following questions:

What kind of optimisation algorithm (maybe few parameters optimisation algorithms) I should use to get decreasing loss (and not converging to large values)?

I am new to this problem and searched a lot of resourced but did not got any satisfactory answer and have been stuck for many days now.

Comment: You write that you want to find the optimal parameters for your model given the observations - have you considered [tag:maximum-likelihood] estimation?
Also, your question actually contains many questions. Consider reducing the scope of your question, see the [help section](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on that.

Comment: Thanks @deemel for the reply. I have edited the question. I can be totally wrong but how can I use maximum-likelihood method as I have been given the target probabilities of each event (x1, x2) pair also in the dataset.

Comment: So method which should be employed will surely be supervised, that's what I though but again I can be completely wrong to model this as a regression problem.

Comment: I have target probabilities of each event and have model i.e let's say gaussian with few parameters which gives theoretical probabilities, apply a loss on predicted and target and find optimal parameters in order to decrease the loss. That's the way I though I can model it. Thanks once again !!